# How to find a bound

Tags: real-analysis, functions, inequality

Let $\nu\gg 1$ be a parameter.

For all $t>0,$ we consider
\begin{align}
A(t) & =\frac{1-\cos(t\sqrt{4\nu-1})}{4\nu-1}-(\cosh(t)-1) \\
g(t) & =\frac{2A(t)}{\frac{\sin(t\sqrt{4\nu-1})}{\sqrt{4\nu-1}}+\sinh(t)+A(t)} \\
f(t) & =\frac{\nu t^3 \mathrm{e}^{-t\nu^\frac{1}{3}}}{\ln(1-g(t))}
\end{align}

> I  want to prove that there exists a constant $c>0$ which doesn't depend on the parameter $\nu$ such that:

$$f\left(\frac{3}{\nu^{\frac{1}{3}}}\right)\le c$$

Please help me to do so.
this is what i tried to do:
 $$f\left(\frac{3}{\nu^{\frac{1}{3}}}\right)  =\frac{3^3 \mathrm{e}^{-3}}{\ln\left(1-g\left(\frac{3}{\nu^{\frac{1}{3}}}\right)\right)}$$ so we need to show that there exists a constant $c'>0$ which doesn't depend on $\nu$ such that $$\ln\left(1-g\left(\frac{3}{\nu^{\frac{1}{3}}}\right)\right)\ge c'$$

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on this problem?  What have you tried to do?  It would be helpful if you edited your question to include that context.

Comment: this is what i tried to do: $$f(\frac{3}{\nu^{\frac{1}{3}}})  =\frac{3^3 \mathrm{e}^{-3}}{\ln(1-g(\frac{3}{\nu^{\frac{1}{3}}}))}$$ so we need to show that there exists a constant $c'>0$ which doesn't depend on $\nu$ such that $$\ln(1-g(\frac{3}{\nu^{\frac{1}{3}}})\ge c'$$

Comment: As I said above, it would be helpful if you **edited your question** to include that context.

Comment: @ Xander Henderson, i wrote my thoghts above, i will be greatful if you could help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: here is the graph of the function: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/w93oiwlaah

Comment: In the definition of $A$, what is the radicand?  Should the argument of $\cos$ be $\sqrt{4\nu}-1$ or $\sqrt{4\nu-1}$?

Comment: it is $\sqrt{4\nu-1}$

Comment: This is the same question as https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2559758/42969 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2558378/42969 – how many accounts to you have?

Comment: In fact, I  want to prove that there exists a constant $c>0$ which dosn't depend on the parameter $\nu$ such that:

$$f(t)\le c$$ for all $t>0$ for that i calculate the derivative of $f$ and i find $$f'(t)=e^{-t\nu^{\frac{1}{3}}}\frac{(3t^2-\nu^{\frac{1}{3}}t^3)\Big(1-g(t)\Big)ln(1-g(t))+t^3g'(t)}{(1-g(t))(ln(1-g(t)))^2}$$. We have $g'(t)\le 0$ for all $t>0$. So for all $t\ge \frac{3}{\nu^{\frac{1}{3}}}$ $f$ is decreasing hence $f(t)\le f( \frac{3}{\nu^{\frac{1}{3}}})$ for all $t\ge \frac{3}{\nu^{\frac{1}{3}}}$. That is why i am trying to find a bound for $ f( \frac{3}{\nu^{\frac{1}{3}}})$

Comment: @Martin, i alway forget the pass word that's why i use a different account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first step looks good.  Now, note that
\begin{align}
\ln\left( 1 - g\left( 3\nu^{-\frac{1}{3}} \right) \right) \ge C
&\iff 1 - g\left( 3\nu^{-\frac{1}{3}} \right) \ge C \\
&\iff g\left( 3\nu^{-\frac{1}{3}} \right) \le C,
\end{align}
where the first equivalence follows from the fact that $\ln$ is increasing, and the second equivalence follows by basic algebra (and absorbing some extra terms into the constant—the constant on the first and second lines are different constants; can you work out the details?).

Evaluating this last expression, we obtain
$$
C \ge g\left( 3\nu^{-\frac{1}{3}} \right) = \frac{2A\left( 3\nu^{-\frac{1}{3}} \right)}{\frac{\sin\left(3\nu^{-\frac{1}{3}}\sqrt{4\nu-1}\right)}{\sqrt{4\nu-1}}+\sinh\left( 3\nu^{-\frac{1}{3}} \right)+A\left( 3\nu^{-\frac{1}{3}} \right)}.$$
This looks like a godawful mess, but there are some simplifications that we can make.  First, note that $\sin(\theta) \in [-1,1]$ for all $\theta$.  From this, it follows that
$$ -1 \le \sin\left(3\nu^{-\frac{1}{3}}\sqrt{4\nu-1}\right) \le 1 
\implies \frac{-1}{\sqrt{4\nu-1}} \le \frac{\sin\left(3\nu^{-\frac{1}{3}}\sqrt{4\nu-1}\right)}{\sqrt{4\nu-1}} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\nu-1}}. $$
By choosing $\nu$ large enough, we can make the middle term as small as we like (via the Squeeze Theorem).  Hence we can ignore that term (or, if you prefer, we can replace that whole complicated expression in $\sin$ with some small $C_1\in (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$, where $\varepsilon > 0$ is as small as we like).

Next, note that $\lim_{t\to\infty} \sinh(t) = \infty$.  Thus by choosing $\nu$ large enough, we can bound that term from below by a constant, i.e.
$$ \sinh\left( 3\nu^{-\frac{1}{3}} \right) \ge C_2 > \varepsilon > 0$$
for some sufficiently large $C_2$.  Hence
$$
C \ge
\frac{2A\left( 3\nu^{-\frac{1}{3}} \right)}{\frac{\sin\left(3\nu^{-\frac{1}{3}}\sqrt{4\nu-1}\right)}{\sqrt{4\nu-1}}+\sinh\left( 3\nu^{-\frac{1}{3}} \right)+A\left( 3\nu^{-\frac{1}{3}} \right)}
\ge \frac{2A\left( 3\nu^{-\frac{1}{3}} \right)}{C_2 + A\left( 3\nu^{-\frac{1}{3}} \right)}.$$

Finally, we need to deal with $A(3\nu^{-\frac{1}{3}})$ somehow.  Note that
$$ A(3\nu^{-\frac{1}{3}})
= \frac{1-\cos(3\nu^{-\frac{1}{3}}\sqrt{4\nu-1})}{4\nu-1}-(\cosh(3\nu^{-\frac{1}{3}})-1)
$$
As before, the first term (involving the cosine) can be made as small as we like by choosing $\nu$ large enough.  From this, it follows that $A(3\nu^{-\frac{1}{3}})$ is of the order $-\cosh(3\nu^{-\frac{1}{3}})$.  That is, for sufficiently large $\nu$, we have
$$
A(3\nu^{-\frac{1}{3}})
= \frac{1-\cos(3\nu^{-\frac{1}{3}}\sqrt{4\nu-1})}{4\nu-1}-(\cosh(3\nu^{-\frac{1}{3}})-1)
\approx -\cosh(3\nu^{-\frac{1}{3}}),
$$
where the $\approx$ hides a bunch of constants that are small relative to the $\cosh$ term.  This tends to infinity as $\nu$ grows large, so we can choose $\nu$ sufficiently large that $A(3\nu^{-\frac{1}{3}}) > C_2$.  But then
$$C
\ge \frac{2A\left( 3\nu^{-\frac{1}{3}} \right)}{C_2 + A\left( 3\nu^{-\frac{1}{3}} \right)}
\ge \frac{2A\left( 3\nu^{-\frac{1}{3}} \right)}{A\left( 3\nu^{-\frac{1}{3}} \right)}
\approx \frac{2\cosh\left( 3\nu^{-\frac{1}{3}} \right)}{\cosh\left( 3\nu^{-\frac{1}{3}} \right)}
= 2.
$$
Note that we have not concluded that $C \ge 2$ will get the job done—remember that $\approx$ hides some constants.  However, we wanted to show that there was some constant $C$ that bounded $g$.  What we have discovered is that such a constant exists, and that it depends on how we bounded $A(3\nu^{-\frac{1}{3}})$, i.e. it depends on the meaning of $\approx$ when it was first introduced.  The details are left as an exercise.  Note also that we have not explicitly found the constant.  Indeed, I have no idea what this constant might be.  Assuming that there are no mistakes, we just know that it exists.

Comment: and can us apply a DL to prove that $f(t)\le c$ for $t\le \frac{3}{\nu^{\frac{1}{3}}}$?

Comment: A "DL"?  What is that?

Comment: i meam Taylor expansion

Comment: for $t\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\nu-1}}$ is it possible?